# How to serve single 404 page for entire site in ExpressJS?

Tags: express, web-applications, http-status-code-404

I'm building out an Express web app slowly but surely and want to add a specific page to return when a 404 response occurs.  Here's what I have so far:

**app.js**

```
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
res.send("What are you looking for???", 404);
});
```

This is after all of my middleware, route imports (I have them modularized in other files), and right before the listener fires to start the app.  As it stands now, this text is shown anytime there's a 404 on the root route (/), but doesn't not display when I'm farther down in the site's directory.  For example, if I'm in a subdirectory like /players/PageThatDoesNotExist no error page displays and the app times out.

What can I do to rectify this and ensure this is fired anytime there's a page not found on the app?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you override all other routes with it and respond to any incoming request with 404 status. Try to register 404 route handler like this and make sure it goes after all your other routes.

```
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.status(404).render('404.hbs');
});
```

And then render your entire custom 404 page, or alternatively

```
res.send('<h1>No page found</h1>');
```

Response with some string value